# Definition conflicts with previous value in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, swift2

I updated Xcode to version 7 and Swift 2.0. My application works and there are not any errors in Xcode 6 with Swift 1.2. I now get the error "Definition conflicts with previous value" in method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` and I see Previous definition of '`tableView`' is here

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchPredicate == nil  {
        return arrayItem.count ?? 0
    } else {
        return arrayFilterOfNames.count ?? 0
    }
}
```

Error is here

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("artistTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SongsCellArtist

        if searchPredicate == nil  {
        var currentString = arrayItem[indexPath.row]
        var urlULTRA: NSURL!
            var ultraDirectory = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
            if var ultraURL: NSURL = ultraDirectory.first as? NSURL {
                urlULTRA = ultraURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentString)
            }
            var ultraMediaPlayer = AVPlayerItem(URL: urlULTRA)
            var ultraCommonMetaData = ultraMediaPlayer.asset.commonMetadata 
            for ultraData in ultraCommonMetaData {
                if ultraData.commonKey == "title" {
//                    println("ultra data equals \(ultraData.stringValue)")
                    nameSongForPass = ultraData.stringValue
                }
                if ultraData.commonKey == "artist" {
                    nameArtistForPass = ultraData.stringValue
                }
                if ultraData.commonKey == "album" {
                    nameAlbumForPass = ultraData.stringValue
                }
                if ultraData.commonKey == "artwork" {
                    imageSongForPass = ultraData.dataValue
                }
            }

            cell.nameSong?.text = nameSongForPass
            if nameAlbumForPass != nil {
                cell.artistAlbumName?.text = "\(nameArtistForPass) - \(nameAlbumForPass)"
            } else {
                cell.artistAlbumName?.text = "\(nameArtistForPass)"
            }

            if imageSongForPass != nil {
                cell.imageSongs?.image = UIImage(data: imageSongForPass)
            } else {
                cell.imageSongs?.image = UIImage(named: "Notes100.png")
        }
        } else {
            var name: String! = arrayFilterOfNames[indexPath.row]
            cell.nameSong.text = name
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I had the same issue when I commented out excess closing curly brace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is declared as optional

```
... -> UITableViewCell?
```

**Edit:** Actually it depends on the Swift version.
Meanwhile the signature of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has changed to the non-optional return type.

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely the "{}" issue.Please check you correctly closed the curly bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Check the tableview `delegate functions are outside of Viewdidload`, and that the table delegates and datasources are correctly set.

For me, I had the functions withing viewdidload, taking it out and building again worked in Swift 2.2

Answer (score 1):

For it was using the same parameter name twice in the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration to:

```
override func tableView(tv: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
```

or change your property name.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error because I was doing something like:

```
func doSomething (param1: String, param1: String){
    print(param1)
    print(param1)
}
```

This was because both my arguments are `param1` ! I actually wanted to write `param` and `param2`.

Learned it the hard way!